# Como solucionar error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, array

Soy algo nuevo en esto, estoy tratando de mostrar todos los productos de la tabla `tb_productos` pero no funciona marcando el error:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Este es el error que marca:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la linea 239 que marca el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta la estructura `HTML` que debería permitir mostrar los
productos:

Por medio del `id="agrega-registros"` y `id="pagination"` a la función `pagination()`

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div style="overflow: scroll;" class="col-xs-12 registros" id="agrega-registros">              
</div>
<center><ul class="pagination" id="pagination"></ul></center> 
/div>
```

Esta es la función en la que se marca el error:

```
function pagination(partida){

    var url = 'paginardisponibles.php';

    $.ajax({

        type:'POST',

        url:url,

        data:'partida='+partida,

        success:function(data){

            var array = eval(data);

            $('#agrega-registros').html(array[0]); **Aqui marca el Error**

            $('#pagination').html(array[1]);

        }

    });

    return false;

}
```

Este es el código en `paginardisponibles.php`, los campos están justo como en la base de datos:

```
    $registro = ("SELECT * FROM tb_productos LIMIT $limit, $nroLotes ");
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$registro);

    $tabla = $tabla.'<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                        <tr>
                <th width="50">#</th>
                <th width="50">Codigo Producto</th>
                <th width="150">Descripcion</th>
                <th width="50">Cantidad</th>
                <th width="150" >Estado</th>
                <th width="100">Costo</th>  
                <th width="150" >KARDEX</th>
                <th width="100">Lote</th> 
                <th width="150">Fecha Caducidad</th>
                        </tr>';
    if(!empty($resultado)){  
    $i=1;
    while($registro2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $tabla = $tabla.'<tr>
                    <td>'.$i++.'</td>
                    <td>'.$registro2['cod_prod'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registro2['descripcion'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registro2['cantidad'].'</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white" class="label-success">'.utf8_decode($registro2['estado']).'</td>
                    <td>'.$registro2['precio_costo'].'</td>
                    <td>'.'<a>>>>>>Ver Kardex<<<<<</a>'.'</td>
                    <td>'.$registro2['lote'].'</td>
                    <td>'.fechaNormal($registro2['fecha_vencimiento']).'</td>                     
                    </tr>';
    }


    $tabla = $tabla.'</table>';
  }


    $array = array(0 => $tabla,
                   1 => $lista);

    echo json_encode($array);
```

De antemano gracias por su tiempo y colaboración, disculpen la molestia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era con: utf8_decode(); no estaba implementado,
solor era hacer utf8_decode($registro2['descripcion']); y ya funciono todo, gracias a la ayuda de @marcos.